# How to manage and store datasets used to train Computer Vision models?

Tags: dataset

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but I am looking for an insightful answer.

I have been working as a Data Scientist for one year now. Currently at the company that I work at, we store all the data in Google Drive. We train deep learning models. Since we work with Computer Vision we store images and videos. We do a lot of data labeling as well. We use different formats for the labeled data. We do a lot of data combinations between different datasets. We collect data on our environments. Currently we do not get data from our clients, but we plan to do it in the future.

Our problem is that it is hard to find, explore, maintain and combine data by storing in Google Drive folders and subfolders which go deeper and deeper.
Usually we combine many different datasets, and then the same one we combine with the new one. So, we do every possible combination. We have a lot of duplication of data as well.

I have tried to find any tool or whatever works for our case but unfortunately I could not find it.

Can you please advise me on that how I can tackle this problem.

Thank you in advance!